# Zapier dynamic dropdown on condition

Tags: zapier

I'm updating a Zapier APP through the Web builder. I need to add two fields:

The label of the first is "Vat Description", and is a text input field;
The second is "Vat Nature", a dropdown list.

I want to make this field required only if the value of the first is 0, or 0%

Any suggestions? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

This is pretty straightforward to do. You want to put the second field in a function, which will generate it dynamically based on the contents of the first field. You can adjust whether or not it's required.

There's docs about this [here](https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform-cli#customdynamic-fields).